# Connect to Heroku redis from a nestjs app

Tags: heroku, redis, nestjs, heroku-redis

I am hosting my nestjs application on Heroku and trying to use "Heroku redis" add-on with it.

In the `app.module.ts` I am importing `RedisModule` as follows:

```js
@Module({
 imports: [
  RedisModule.register({ host: process.env.REDIS_URL }) 
 ]
})
```

After configuring Heroku-redis add-on, it added `REDIS_URL` under config vars in Heroku, however, when I deploy and run the application, I get the following error message:

`2020-06-11T09:00:48.690255+00:00 app[web.1]: [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis://h:abc@ec2-52-51-206-63.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:16719`

(I've replaced the real url value with a sample one to illustrate the problem)

I can't seem to find

Answer (score 2):

```
RedisModule.register({ url: process.env.REDIS_URL })
```